# Capture embedded CKEditor afterPaste(e) event in TypeScript/Angular2 parent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ckeditor4.x

I have an Angular2 html that includes a ckeditor as a child:

```
<div [class.hover-toolbar]="hideToolbar">
    <ckeditor
            [config]="{
              toolbar: toolbar,
              readOnly: isReadOnly,
              height: fieldHeight,
              width: auto
            }"
            (focus)="editorOnFocus($event)"
            (blur)="editorOnBlur($event)"
            (change)="propagateChange($event)"
            (afterPaste)="cleanAndPropagate($event)"
            debounce="10">
    </ckeditor>
</div>
```

The CKEditor documents [here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterPaste) indicate that an *afterPaste* event exists:

[image]

The code of the CKEditorComponent that we pulled in does not have an EventEmitter() for the afterPaste event, and the change event is not triggered by paste:

[image]

I need to generate an event from the CKEditor that I can catch in my enclosing component **after** a paste completes (the paste event fired before the content resolves will not work).

How can I cause the CKEditor to emit an event after a paste resolves?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by regenerating the CKEditor code at https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder/ and adding the "Clipboard" plugin to the editor. Unfortunately, the docs I was looking at made no mention of the fact that the functionality was buried in a plugin and the version that we had did not include all plugins.

Moral of the story - if the docs say an event is supposed to be generated and it's demonstrably NOT being generated by the CKEditor, check your plugins and make sure you've included the correct set.